# react-native-map Error converting bytecode to dex:WithDexForDebug

Tags: android, react-native-maps

I've lost 2 days already and I simply can't build a react-native project that uses react-native-map.  This is the error I get when I run `react-native run-android`

> Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:WithDexForDebug Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzg;
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzg;

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "hackathon",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I've already ran `react-native rlink react-native-maps`.

Also, here is my `android/build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            //url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hackathon"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I am doing my development from Windows 10.  In my Android Studio, I'm pretty sure I installed Google Play Services.  When I look in my computer HDD, I do see the existence of Google Play Services:10.0.1.

How do I get my project to compile such that I can use `react-native-maps` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'` from my `android/app/build.gradle` file and then everything worked.

Comment: but didnt it make something to crash? i mean didn't you need this configuration?